# How to change the defaults alignment to left in pygtk?

Tags: windows, gtk, pygtk, glade

Every program that I'm making using pygtk is right-alignment by default (maybe because my default language is right to left language?)
How can I change it? 
[image: pygtk right alignment example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orientation of the widgets in a container depends on the locale. You can change the locale settings on Windows by setting the LANG environment variable.

```
set LANG=en_US
something.py
```

On Linux you can do the same with the following commands

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US
something.py
```

or simply

```
LANGUAGE=en_US something.py
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to adjust direction of widgets inside a widget (for example a window), regardless of system locale:

```
widget.set_direction(gtk.TEXT_DIR_LTR)
```

And to change default direction for everything inside your app:

```
gtk.widget_get_default_direction(gtk.TEXT_DIR_LTR)
```

Or gtk.TEXT_DIR_RTL instead of LTR